# amp-list height doesn't update

Tags: amp-html

I am triyng to get working this dynamic amp-list getting data from dynamic json.
Everithing works fine but the amp-list is not dynamic, it should change after every loading

```
<amp-list class="products-category" width="auto" height="700" layout="fixed-height" [src]="myState.items" src="/dropshipping/__AMP_get_products.php" id="show-more-list">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <a href="{{url}}" class="tile" role="listitem">
           <amp-img width="130" height="130" layout="fixed" alt="{{name}}" src="{{img}}"></amp-img>
           <div class="product_name">{{name}}</div>
           <div class="short_description">{{description}}</div>
           <div class="price">
                <span class="list-price">&euro;{{list-price}}</span>
                <span class="sell-price">&euro;{{sell-price}}</span>
           </div>
        </a>
    </template>
</amp-list>

<amp-state id="myState" src="/dropshipping/__AMP_get_products.php"></amp-state>
    <form method="GET" action="/dropshipping/__AMP_get_products.php" action-xhr="/dropshipping/__AMP_get_products.php" target="_top"
        on="submit-success: AMP.setState({
            myState: { items: myState.items.concat(event.response.items)},
            product: {index: product.index + 1,
            hasMorePages: event.response.hasMorePages}
        });">
        <input type="hidden" name="index" value="0" [value]="product.index">
        <input type="submit" value="Mostra altri prodotti" [class]="(product.hasMorePages == false ? 'hide' : 'ampstart-btn caps m1 mb3 show')">
    </form>
```

https://www.nutritioncenter.it/proteine/?amp

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `amp-list is not dynamic, it should change after every loading`. If you change your JSON, the changes will be available on click/refresh. However, I don't see a .json file. `myState.items` won't work. Further, the site storing `src` must be HTTPS and CORS enabled.

Comment: Sorry for my english, i mean "amp-list HEIGHT is not dynamic, after click on the button new items are loaded from the json into html but the amp-list height still remain the same".. you can see the online demo on the link above.

The json file is correctly specified on the code is: https://www.nutritioncenter.it/dropshipping/__AMP_get_products.php HTTPS and CORS are enabled.

Comment: see issue [#10230](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10230) and [#11251](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/11251) on GitHub, maybe that will help

Answer (score 1):

Try [AMP-Live-List](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-live-list/). AMP-List is static.

Comment: Ok amp-live-list tried but doesn't work as expected. It works with timestamp and is not usefull in this case. Solved using amp-list with fixed height and smooth scroll to top after button click :) thanks